# iOS app store short link and itunes affiliate program

Tags: ios, app-store

I would like to use app store short links within my apps with my PHG affiliate token. Does anyone know if short links work with the affiliate token? I did a bit of testing and I am not seeing clicks for the URL in the PHG console, so I am thinking it is not working or I screwed up the URL.

short links are of the following format: `AppStore.com/Apple`.

Here is the link I am attempting to use.

```
http://appstore.com/tardentappsinc?at=xxx&ct=xxx
```

Comment: Wow. People actually go through a question and fix grammatical errors. I shall not be so lazy next time around. :)